# Grid view cell spacing in edit mode is asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

When I click edit in purchase tab grid view cell mode is fine but in sales tab grid view cell mode not accurate what i want....i don't understand what should i do now...i want sales tab cell mode as purchase tab cell mode. hope you can help me

I'm including picture for better understand

[image]

> and its html code

```html
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="dataGridTable" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" HeaderStyle-Height="30" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" PageSize="30" DataKeyNames="invoiceNumber,productName,productCategory" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true"/>
                                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="invoiceNumber" HeaderText="Invoice" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="invoiceNumber" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="productName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="productName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="productCategory" HeaderText="Category" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="productCategory" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="totalQuantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="totalQuantity" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="totalPurchasePrice" HeaderText="Total Price" SortExpression="totalPurchasePrice" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="salePricePerItem" HeaderText="Sale Price/Item" SortExpression="salePricePerItem" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="comments" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="comments" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="date" />

                                
                                 <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="24px" ImageUrl="~/Images/detailsInfo.png" Width="24px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>

                            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="gridHeaderAlignment" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

[image]

> and its html code

```html
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="dataGridTable" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"  AllowPaging="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" HeaderStyle-Height="30" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" PageSize="30" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="invoiceNumber,productName,productCategory">
                            <Columns>
                               
                                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="invoiceNumber" HeaderText="Invoice" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="invoiceNumber" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="productName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="productName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="productCategory" HeaderText="Category" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="productCategory" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="totalQuantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="totalQuantity" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="totalPrice" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="totalPrice" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="paidAmount" HeaderText="Paid Amount" SortExpression="paidAmount" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="comments" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="comments" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="Date" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="date" />

                                 <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="24px" ImageUrl="~/Images/detailsInfo.png" Width="24px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                               
                            </Columns>

                            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="gridHeaderAlignment" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Want do you mean by "i want sales tab cell mode as purchase tab cell mode"? Only difference I can see is not taking full row width for textbox in Sale grid.

Comment: Yes i want full row width for textbox in sale grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `ItemStyle` and `ControlStyle` property of bound field. ItemStyle modifies the style for gridview column and ControlStyle modifies the style for control present in gridview column.

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="totalQuantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="totalQuantity" />
       <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
       <ControlStyle Width="100%" />
    </asp:BoundField>
```

Adjust the width as per your wish.
You could also use ControlStyle-CssClass or ItemStyle-CssClass, if you want to generalized you style.